# Symfony2 Crawler keeps returning Relocation Page

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, salesforce

I'm trying to scrape a web page, but this particular page keeps returning if and else statements containing `window.location.replace('web_address');` and if I do an `echo $crawler->html();` then it actually redirects my web application to that new web page that I'm actually trying to scrape.

The page is Salesforce. I'm not sure if they just have some kind of mechanism in place that uses redirects for any incoming page request. I'm able to securely get logged in, but I just can't retrieve actual page content.

Does anyone know a way around this or perhaps a different way to do `$client->request('GET', $link);`?

Thanks

(Edit: actual return I get in code/crawler)

```
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { 
    SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://company.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp'); 
} 
else if (window.location.replace) { 
    window.location.replace('https://company.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp'); 
} 
else { 
    window.location.href ='https://company.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp'; 
}
```

How can I get around this? Can I not just somehow get the actual page content from a page on Salesforce, or will ever scrape/goute/curl return a redirect like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to just use the RESTful API.

[Here's a super easy article how to do it using PHP.](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php)

You will need a SalesForce Developer Edition account in order to create an API key.